# Diophantine equation $p^{3}-q^{5}=(p+q)^{2}$

Tags: number-theory

$p$,$q$ are prime numbers.

solve the equation  $~p^{3}-q^{5}=(p+q)^{2}$.

I tried but got only that $p$,$q$ are both $1$ (mod $4$) or $3$ (mod $4$).
Could you help me?

Comment: Umm.... I feel your deduction is rather trivial as all primes greater than 4 are odd, implying that they are 1 or 3 modulo 4.

Comment: To add, $p=7$ and $q=3$ work out.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am very poor at number theory.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$p^3-q^5=(p+q)^2=p^2+2pq+q^2$$
So, $p^3-q^5\ge 0$, so $p^3\ge q^5$, so $p>q$.
$$p^2(p-1)=p^3-p^2=q^5+2pq+q^2=q(q^4+2p+q)$$

Hence, $p^2$ divides $q^4+2p+q$ and so $q$ divides (p-1).

So $p^2\le q^4+2p+q$, so $p\le q^2+1$. We can then verify that $q=2$ has no solution for $p$.

$p$ is prime, and $q^2+1$ and $q^2$ are not:
$$q<p\le q^2-1$$

let $p=aq+b$ with $1\le a< q$ and $1\le b<q$.

We get $$q^5=p^3-(p+q)^2=(b^3-b^2)+q.(\dots)$$
Hence $q$ divides $b^2(b-1)$, so $b=1$

Hence $p=aq+1$ with $1\le a< q$

We get $$q^5=p^3-(p+q)^2=q.(3a-2(a+1))+q^2.(\dots)$$

Hence, $q$ divides $a-2$, so $a=2$.

So $p=2q+1$

$$q^5=q^2.(8q+12-9)$$
$$0=q^3-8q-3=(q-3).(q^2+3q+1)$$

Therefore the only positive integer solution is $q=3$ and so $p=7$.

Comment: You go a long way to show that $b=1$, but that is obvious from $q\mid p-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

Fixing $q$, you have the cubic equation $p^3-p^2-2qp=q^5+q^2)$.

So $p$ must divide $q^2(q^3+1)$. But if $p=q$ then $p^3-q^5<0<(p+q)^2$, so we must have $p\mid q^3+1$.

Similarly, you get $q\mid p^3-p^2$ or $q\mid p-1$.